# Unable to pass headers

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

How to pass SOAP  headers  and body separately  in mule soft  while consuming external SOAP web services?we are using any point studio 6 with 3.9 runtime stand alone.

Comment: Can you please detail the specific problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s not enough info in the question to give a detailed answer. But I assume you are using the ws:consumer to consume soap services.
To add specific soap headers using the ws consumer, use the `set-property` component and prefix the header name with ‘soap.’

For example:

```
<set-property propertyName="soap.Authorization"
value="<auth>Bearer
MWYxMDk4ZDktNzkyOC00Z</auth>"/>
```

More info here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mulesoft-docs/blob/master/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/web-service-consumer.adoc